# Access vba sql that match only one

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I have a table that has several repeated records. So I want to take those that were repeated twice and then check if only one of them is having a value of -99 in the total column, so if both of them have -99 it will ignore them but if only one of them has -99 than it will take the values of the second to calculate them and assign the result to the one with -99.

```
---------------------------------------------
Name        | N1           | N2              |
----------------------------------------------
A           | 500          | 300             |
----------------------------------------------
A           | 0            | **-99**         |
----------------------------------------------
B           | 60           | -99             |
----------------------------------------------
B           | 77           | -99             |
----------------------------------------------
C           | 0            | -99             |
----------------------------------------------
C           | 15           | 100             |
----------------------------------------------
C           | 30           | -9              |
----------------------------------------------
```

For example here it will ignore B because both are having -99 AND C because count=3, but for A it will update the -99 row to be: 500-300 =200

```
---------------------------------------------
Name        | N1           | N2              |
----------------------------------------------
A           | 500          | 300             |
----------------------------------------------
A           | 0            | **200**         |
----------------------------------------------
```

I've done some of the code but didn't know ho to complete it:

```vb
        Private Sub GET_TWO_COU()

            Dim COUs As Variant
            Dim p As Variant
            Dim sql As String
            Dim STR As New ADODB.Recordset


     sql = "SELECT DISTINCT NAME FROM STR_TBL"
    STR.Open sql, cnn, adOpenStatic
    STR.MoveLast
    STR.MoveFirst
    COUs = STR.GetRows(STR.RecordCount)
    STR.Close

    For Each p In COUs 

      Q1 = "SELECT NAME FROM STR_TBL"
        STR.Open sql, cnn, adOpenStatic

       Do Until STR.EOF
       DoEvents
               sql = " UPDATE STR_TBL I" _
                    & "Set I.N2 = IIf(I.N2 = -99, DLookup(""N1 - N2"" ," _
                    & """STR_TBL"" , '"[NAME] ='" & p & "' AND N2<> -99""), N2)" _
                    & "WHERE I.[NAME] IN (SELECT I.[NAME] FROM STR_TBL I" _
                    & " GROUP BY I.[NAME] HAVING (Count(I.[NAME]) = 2)" _
                    & "AND (Min(I.N2) <> Max(I.N2))AND (Min(I.N2) = -99 OR Max(I.N2) = -99))"

            DoCmd.SetWarnings False
            DoCmd.RunSQL sql
            DoCmd.SetWarnings True
                      STR.MoveNext
           Loop
           STR.Close
NEXT

     End Sub
```

NOTE: CODE UPDATED

The other issue is that it will add the same value to all the matched rows! why is that happing? Am I doing something wrong in my loop?

Comment: I'm thinking this question should be rolled back to a previous edit - you're updating your question with the responses supplied in the answer, so no one knows what your original code looks like unless they look through your edits.  (also the the supplied answer shouldn't be in a loop - it works on all records in one hit).

Comment: I did it without a loop and it assigned a null value to all the matched !

Comment: It worked for me using the figures in your post.  You're not using it with VBA are you?  Just add the SQL as a new query and run it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider a pure SQL solution with a nuanced `UPDATE` query that includes a subquery in `WHERE` clause, a conditional `IIF()`, and domain aggregate, `DLookUp`.

```sql
UPDATE myTable t
SET t.N2 = IIF(t.N2 = -99, DLookUp("N1-N2", "myTable", "[Name]='" & t.[Name] & "' AND N2 <> -99"), N2)
WHERE t.[Name] IN (SELECT t.[Name]
                   FROM myTable t
                   GROUP BY t.[Name]
                   HAVING (Count(t.[Name]) = 2) 
                      AND (Min(t.N2) <> Max(t.N2)) 
                      AND (Min(t.N2) = -99 OR Max(t.N2) = -99))
```

Before table

```sql
Name    N1   N2
A      500  300
A        0  -99
B       60  -99
B       77  -99
C        0  -99
C       15  100
C       30   -9
```

After table

```sql
Name    N1   N2
A      500  300
A        0  200
B       60  -99
B       77  -99
C        0  -99
C       15  100
C       30   -9
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply.. I updated the code with you suggestions as you can see above in my code, but I got an error says syntax error in the update?

Comment: there is an issue I just noticed is that it will add the same value to all the matched rows! why is that happing? Am I doing something wrong in my loop?

Comment: Why is the update query in a loop? This answer avoids any VBA. It updates all needed rows. Just run the SQL query **once** with `DoCmd.OpenQuery "myupdatequery"`. If problem persists without loop, edit post with data to show how it *adds the same value to all matched rows* (unclear as update does not add).